# Pegar o atributo de varias div's e enviar uma de cada vez para outra função

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando pegar o atributo de cada div e enviar uma de cada vez, mas está dando erro, o código que tentei fazer e este:

```js
function deletarTudo() {
  var lista = document.querySelectorAll("#lista div").getAttribute("id");
  for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    controle("adicionar", lista[i]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está usando errado o `.getAttribute("id")`. O `querySelectorAll` irá gerar uma lista de nós, logo você deve pegar o atributo de cada nó individualmente no laço `for`.

No caso do `id`, você pode usar apenas `lista[i].id` em vez de `.getAttribute("id")`:

```js
function deletarTudo() {
  var lista = document.querySelectorAll("#lista div");
  for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    controle("adicionar", lista[i].id);
  }
}


function controle(x,y){
   console.log(x,y)
}

deletarTudo();
```

```html
<div id="lista">
   <div id="id1">div1</div>
   <div id="id2">div2</div>
   <div id="id3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function deletarTudo() {
  var lista = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    controle("adicionar", lista[i].getAttribute("id"));
  }
};
```

talves assim funcione

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi referido o `document.querySelectorAll("#lista div")` retorna uma lista, tipo array e não podes ir buscar as IDs diretamente, tens de iterar. Assim podias fazer com menos código o seguinte:

```
function deletarTudo() {
  var lista = document.querySelectorAll("#lista div");
  lista.forEach(el => controle("adicionar", el.id));
};
```

Exemplo:

```js
const controle = (metodo, id) => console.log(metodo, id); // só para o exemplo

function deletarTudo() {
  var lista = document.querySelectorAll("#lista div");
  lista.forEach(el => controle("adicionar", el.id));
};


deletarTudo();
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```